# Execute service method periodically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

So, I have a service:

```
@Stateless
public void SomeService {

    public void someAction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I have a config file `timer.properties` which contains following string:

```
refresh.interval=1234
```

The question is to find how to automatically execute `someAction()` every 1234 seconds? I tried `@Schedule`, but it works only with constants. The application must read value from config (already implemented with `@Startup.. @PostConstruct` bean method) and set this value as execution interval for `someMethod()`.

Comment: Can you use something like a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)?  I'm not very familiar with the EJB spec, but I remember it has weird restrictions about threading.

Comment: @azurefrog "Specifically, enterprise beans should not (...) create or manage threads." - says EJB specification. There wont be a good style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found acceptable answer myself. So, if you need to call some method in your EJB periodically, you could do it with excellent `TimerService` in EJB spec.

One of possible solutions will be following:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class RepeatableService {

    @EJB
    private SomeService service;

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    private long repeatInterval = 1234000L; // in milliseconds

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        timerService.createIntervalTimer(0L,
                repeatInterval, new TimerConfig(null, false));
    }

    @Timeout
    public void process(Timer timer) {
        doAction();
    }

    public void doAction() {
        System.out.println("Action called!");
        service.someAction();
    }

}
```

For more info, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) and [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) links.

Answer (score 0):

Your class must implement TimerDemoRemote interface

```
@Stateless
public void SomeService implements TimerDemoRemote{

    @Resource
   private SessionContext context;

    public void MyTimer(long duration) {
      //There are many variants of createTimer you can choose the one that you require.
      context.getTimerService().createTimer(Long initialDuration,long intervalDuration,Serializable info);
   }

    @Timeout
public void doMyTask(Timer timer){
      //call those methods that you require I mean someAction() etc.. 
   }


    public void someAction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..