# Bean starts with the application server, and run method every 10 seconds

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, background-process

I need to create a bean that allows to clean a database. So that it runs at server startup and every 10 seconds (for example).

How can I handle it?

EDIT:

I've tried with @Startup, @Singleton and @Schedule annotation but it doesn't start.

Comment: Did you already look at the quartz-scheduler library?

Comment: No. The biggest problem is that I can not start the EJB on server startup.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386639/execute-service-method-periodically

Answer (score 1):

`@Startup` is the way to got but in some cases Wildfly runs the beans some minutes after the start (like Wildfly would roll a dice or something). To be completely sure, have a bean similar to the following:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class BeanToRunOnStartup {

    @PostConstruct
    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/10", second="*")
    public void doStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is necessary to set somethings in order to make it start at Wildfly's launch?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question - when you want to be completely sure I recommend a combination of  `@Schedule` (for scheduling) and `@Startup` (for, yes, the sake of starting up),`@PostConstruct` and `@Singleton` to enforce a run on startup directly after the bean is being constructed.

Comment: I mean, to run the "@Startup" bean is necessary to set something, for example in web.xml?

Comment: Nope, it's an EJB-annotation-only thing.

Comment: I did as you told me, but the bean does not start by itself. What could be wrong?

Comment: Reduce the bean by the `Schedule` annotation as this is the minimal example of a bean ran at startup (http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/how-to-create-an-ejb-startup-service) - if this does not work, perhaps check common Wildfly bugs.

Comment: I would not mix `@PostConstruct` and `@Schedule`. `@PostConstruct` is intended to be run once after EJB construction by the container. It should really contain logic that normally would be in a POJO's constructor. Put the logic you want to re-occur in a separate method with the `@Schedule` annotation. You might also want to take a look at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/ejb/timer which should work on wildfly as this repo is maintained by RedHat guys.

Comment: Specifically https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/ejb/timer/src/main/java/org/javaee7/ejb/timer/TimerSessionBean.java is an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, in your opinion it is better to have 1) a `@PostConstruct` annotated method, 2) a `@Schedule` annotated method and 3) a "normal" method being called from 1 and 2? Obvious unecessary code overhead, IMHO.